# Show that $f \in L(X, \textbf{X}, \mu)$ and $\int f d\mu = 0$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

> The following question is Exercise 5B from the book *Elements of Integration*, by R.G. Bartle:
>
> [image]

**Here is my attempt so far:**

We know that $|f|\ge 0$ and so $|f| \in M^+(X,\textbf{X},\mu)$. Also, since $f =0$ $\mu$-almost everywhere on $X$, we also have that $|f|=0$ $\mu$-almost everywhere on $X$.

Since $|f|\in M^+(X,\textbf{X},\mu) $ and $|f|=0$ $\mu$-almost everywhere on $X$., we get from Corollary 4.10 in Bartle (listed below), that $$\int |f| d\mu = 0,$$ i.e. $|f| \in L(X,\textbf{X},\mu)$ and, consequently, $f \in L(X, \textbf{X}, \mu)$.

The only thing left for me to show, is that $$\int f d\mu = 0.$$ Can anyone please help guide me in the right direction?

> **Corollary 4.10:** Suppose that $f \in M^+$. Then $f(x) =0$ $\mu$-almost everywhere on $X$ if and only if $$\int f d\mu = 0.$$

Comment: Very old question, but in this exercise Bartle speaks of X measurable real valued function, not extended real valued function, so it could be even easier to prove it compared to the answer you gave, which is anyway more generic...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: use the "triangle inequality" for integrals, i.e., $$\left| \int f \right| \leq \int \lvert f \lvert.$$

Comment: Oh yes of course! How did I miss that? lol! Thank you! :)